# What are the various aspects with which a request is matched in a browser's cache?

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser, user-agent

Which of the following requests are considered different in a browser's cache?

```
a) GET http://mywebsite.com/home
b) GET http://www.mywebsite.com/home
c) POST http://mywebsite.com/home
d) POST http://www.mywebsite.com/home
e) GET http://mywebsite.com/home?param=testparam
f) POST http://mywebsite.com/home?param=testparam
```

Suppose if the the request varies only in headers, is it considered different?
Ex. Is

```
Accept: text/xml
GET http://mywebsite.com/home?param=testparam
```

different from

```
Accept: text/json
GET http://mywebsite.com/home?param=testparam
```

If they aren't different, is there a way I can make the browser treat them as different requests based on the HTTP Verb / Header?

Is there an RFC spec which defines this behavior for browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: There always is RFC specs... Using google: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them a different. The normative spec indeed is RFC 7234. (In particular, read about the "Vary" header field).